# Get SSL pem certificate of a webpage using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, ssl, webdriver, pem, certificate-authority

I need to retrieve an information on some webpages using the Python Requests library. The problem is that, for some of those webpages, the SSL chain is broken (we don't have the intermediaries), so Requests raises a SSLError "unable to get local issuer certificate". I could ask Requests to not check the SSL (verify=False) however I do not want to for security reasons.

When accessing the same page via a web browser, this problem is no more because browsers are doing AIA fetching to retrieve missing intermediaries in a SSL chain, so I thought I would use headless Selenium instead of Requests, because it's using an actual browser, so the AIA fetching would be done. This is actually working, so I use requests and if I have an SSL error, I switch to Selenium. However, for reasons that are not relevant for this question, I would like to use only Requests to actually get the information, so I would like to pass to request the correct .pem file (using "verify=PATH_TO_PEM"). What I would like is to get this completed pem file from Selenium. This is basically, in pseudo-code, what I would like :

```
get_data(url):
  try:
    r = requests.get(url)
    return data_from_response(r)
  except SSLError:
    webdriver.get(url)  # selenium
    ssl_pem = get_pem_file(webdriver)
    r = requests.get(url, verify=ssl_pem)
    return data_from_response(r)
```

What I'm missing is the "get_pem_file" function. Is this possible ? And if so, how ?

Thanks